# Having trouble using JOIN in Oracle SQL to pull required information

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having some trouble finding out the proper way to approach this question.

```
Database tables:
Student(stdID[pk], stdName, stdSet)
Enrollment(stdID[pk], crsID[pk], year[pk], semester[pk], grade)
Offering(crsID[pk], year[pk], semester[pk], instrID)
Course(crsID[pk], crsTitle, creditHrs)
Instructor(instrID[pk], instrName, dept)
```

"Find all instructors who had taught, from 2006 to 2008, a given student A01234567. List the student ID, instructorID, and year. Do not duplicate rows."

What I originally had was this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT stdID, instrID, year
FROM Student s
JOIN Instructor i ON Offering o (o.instrID = i.instrID)
JOIN Offering o ON Course c (c.crsID = o.crsID)
WHERE stdID = 'A01234567'
    AND date BETWEEN (2006 AND 2008);
```

However, this is not entirely correct. I have notes that it's something to do with "missing 2 columns from Offering join", but I don't know what that means...

Comment: Is this homework?  What is the actual (assumedly unique) key of table `Offering`?  Hint: you can only have one primary key per table.

Comment: No, it's studying. That's exactly how my teacher put out the question...I can only guess that it's stdID as primary key for Offering

Comment: Studying is close enough to homework.  I often find that a quick 'test instance' database is _really_ handy.  Pick up one of the 'Express' editions of the relevant RDBMSs (which can be had for free) that'll work on your local machine, create the tables, then see what the query does.  Of note - one of the tables in your query is not necessary.  As for `Offering` - think, how many years might a particular course be offered?  And why is it not directly related to students (why is `stdId` _not_ in the table, much less part of the 'pk' - primary key)?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I was looking at the wrong table. I meant to say I think crsID is the primary key for Offering. Regrettably my teacher has been quite vague on teaching us proper SQL all semester and he puts together makeshift tables to ask us questions from.

Comment: Okay, perhaps a better hint: primary keys can comprise more than one column in a table.  Also, your query is currently missing a table that you'll need (actually, you technically reference two tables you don't need).  Really, these tables aren't too terribly designed; I'd probably do the overall design a bit different, but this should actually be quite serviceable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, I would start with the `Instructor` table, since that's what I want to return.

I'd join that to the `Offering` table, so I have all the `Offering` for each instructor.

(But we don't really need anything from the `Instructor` table at all, since we have InstrId in the `Offering` table.)

Then I'd join that to `Enrollment`, to basically get all the students that were enrolled in each course offering.

Then I'd join that to `Student`. But again, we don't really need anything from the `Student` table, we already have `stdId` in the `Enrollment` table.

The tricky part is that join between `Offering` and `Enrollment`. The join predicate will need to be on `year` and `semester`, as well as `crsId`.

So, to satisfy the stated requirements, only two tables need to be queried:

```
SELECT e.stdId
     , o.instrId
     , e.year
  FROM Offering o
  JOIN Enrollment e
    ON e.crsId = o.crsId
   AND e.year = o.year
   AND e.semester = o.semester
 WHERE e.stdID = 'A01234567'
   AND e.year >= 2006
   AND e.year <= 2008
 GROUP
    BY e.stdId
     , o.instrId
     , e.year
 ORDER
    BY e.stdId
     , o.instrId
     , e.year
```

---

There's a peculiarity with the database design. Consider what happens when there are two or more instructors teaching a given course in the same year and semester.

But the student was enrolled in only one of those.

This query will pick up the instructors of both offerings.

It's a problem with the query, but the given database design doesn't give us any way to resolve the issue... because there's no way to tell which instructor the student had.

The query satisfies the stated requirements, but the results will be a bit odd, showing a particular student had six different instructors for 'Calc I' in the fall of 2006.

Unless there's something that's eluding me here.

**EDIT:**

As Emily Litella would have intoned, "Never mind...". There's a unique constraint on the `Offering` table. There can be only one offering of a given `crsId` in a semester. So there's no problem there. (Except that it's peculiar that there would be only one offering of a given course in a given semester.)

<strike>The `GROUP BY` is not necessary. The constraints already guarantee that there will be no duplicate rows returned.</strike>

Actually, I think the GROUP BY is needed, because it's possible that the student was enrolled in two separate courses led by the same instructor.  The purpose of the `GROUP BY` is to eliminate any duplicate rows from the result set (as indicated in the specification.)

Comment: I was assuming that the primary key for `Offering` was unique, meaning that there could be only one instance of a course per year/semester (not unheard of in some small universities/classes).  Which was otherwise bugging me too... but with that consideration in mind, you shouldn't need the `GROUP BY`.  But hey, I wasn't going to make it _this_ easy for him...  I think the rest of us were hoping to prod him into writing this query himself.

Comment: Thank you both, spencer7593 and Clockwork-Muse. I think the part I just wasn't getting was the multiple joins on Enrollment and Offering. For some reason I kept thinking that I needed to do them all separately or something stupid. I can also appreciate not wanting to just give me the answer too as doing is always the better way of learning. I think I'll look at asking better questions in the future. Thanks again! Edit: Is there a reason you don't need distinct in the SELECT?

Comment: @SpaceJesus... we don't need a `DISTINCT` keyword in the SELECT because the included a `GROUP BY` clause already removes duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Your join syntax is not correct.  Here is your query, fixed so it is at least syntactically correct.  That might help you move toward the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT stdID, instrID, year
FROM Instructor i JOIN
     Offering o
     ON o.instrID = i.instrID join
     Course c
     on c.crsID = o.crsID
WHERE stdID = 'A01234567' AND date BETWEEN (2006 AND 2008);
```

Comment: I'll have to play around with that a little and see what I can come up with. Thank you for the correction on syntax.

Comment: Also, the date syntax is wrong.  You want something like `year(date) between 2006 and 2008` or `extract(year from date) between 2006 and 2008`.

Comment: Personally, I'd be very surprised if this ran, as `stdId` doesn't appear in any of the tables you currently reference.